# Подсчет лайков продукта из другой таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть таблица продуктов:

```
product_id |  product_name | ... 
--------------------------------
     1     |     name 1    | ...
     2     |     name 2    | ...
     3     |     name 3    | ...
```

Есть таблица лайков, где хранится `product_id` и `user_id`

```
  like_id  | product_id | user_id
--------------------------------
     1     |     1      | 1
     2     |     2      | 1
     3     |     1      | 2
```

То есть у первого продукта два лайка, у второго один, у третьего нет лайков.

Как мне это подсчитать и вывести в таблицу `products` и если нет лайков вывести пустое поле?

Comment: LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY и COUNT().

Comment: @Akina минут 30 уже не могу обьеденить с помощью `GROUP BY`. Можете подсказать с этим?

Comment: `select p.product_id, p.product_name, count(user_id) as lcount from products as p left join likes as l on (l.product_id = p.product_id) group by p.product_id, p.product_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.product_name,COUNT(*) as cnt FROM products p LEFT JOIN likes l USING(product_id) GROUP BY p.product_id,p.product_name
```

Comment: У вас точно провильно `GROUP BY l.product_id`? Мне кажется должно быть `GROUP BY p.product_id`

Comment: обычно СУБД не дпоускают использования в списке выборки * и прочих полей, не указанных в группировке. Оператор using тоже будет работать не везде, а вернее скорее мало где.

Comment: поправил, USING не встречал чтоб не работало